# Bolding of keywords in Eclipse makes columns not line up

Tags: eclipse, fonts

I've always used the Inconsolata font in Eclipse.  I recently had my hard drive fail, so I had to reinstall everything.  I'm now realizing that columns aren't lining up in Eclipse because when Eclipse bolds some keywords, it makes them wider than the non-bolded version.  I think I would have noticed this before, so it must be some artifact of how I set it up when I reinstalled everything.

What do I need to do to make the font truly non-proportional, so bold text takes the same space as non-bold text?

Comment: Does [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=133256) help? Quote: `I actually found a solution. Installing the infinality patched version of freetype will solve the issue.`